# Same strings but var_dump() says one is 5 characters longer

Tags: php, string

I have 2 strings, when I do `var_dump()` I see one string is 5 characters longer than the other one.

I guess this is because in the first string, the `'` (quote) is seen as `&#039;` 
or `&apos;` (but I am not sure about this).

```
string(15) "i'm a bird" 
string(10) "i'm a bird"
```

I want the first string to have 10 chars aswell.

I already tried `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlspecialchars()` with `ENT_QUOTES`, `htmlspecialchars()` with `ENT_NOQUOTES`, `utf8_decode()`, `utf8_encode()`, ...

It still stays a `string(15)`.

Someone knows how to do it?

EDIT: @  Mathieu Imbert: When I look at the page source, I see it like this:

```
string(15) "i&#039;m a bird"
```

---

SOLUTION:

EDIT: Thanks PeeHaa !! You code @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/pvHCwH fixed it!

```
html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Where do the strings come from? paste the full code, it could be one of those stupid mistakes you don't see but everybody else does xd

Comment: Are you viewing this page from web browser? In that case check the page source and see how the string is encoded. Don't *guess*.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/gtGVZs

Comment: @PeeHaa Any idea why `ENT_QUOTES` and `ENT_NOQUOTES` return different results?

Comment: [ENT_NOQUOTES](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) doesn't handle quotes

Comment: @PeeHaa Seems obvious, but I don't understand how using `ENT_NOQUOTES` makes a difference in `i&#039;m a bird"` http://codepad.org/5pxDJR2y

Comment: Because `&#039;` represents a quote. And you are telling it not to parse it.

Comment: @PeeHaa I am so stupid. I was defeated by english terminology. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first string to be 10 chars aswell, you need to `DECODE` the encoded value in the string. Check [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

The example you give would make the second string also larger then 10 chars.

Comment: $title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_NOQUOTES);
var_dump($title)

This still gives me a string(15)

Comment: You are DECODING so if you use `ENT_NOQUOTES` you are telling PHP not to decode quotes. And decoding quotes is just what you want