# php: unserialize return false but in single php file: return array

Tags: php

I really don't know why.

I've got a sql query which get a serlialized string.
Then I want to unserialize it, and the return is bool(false)!

So I dumped the string and put it in a external file:

```
$str = 'a:1:{i:4;s:13:"notifications";}';
print_r(unserialize($str));
```

And magically, everythings works!
It's literally the same string.

If anyone have an idea on this. Thanks you a lot for helping!

EDIT tried something more:

```
$DB->query("
    SELECT xxxxxx
    FROM xxxxxx
    WHERE ID = $xxxx");
$Paranoia = $DB->next_record()[0];
$arr = array(0=>'test');
$Paranoia2 = serialize($arr); 
var_dump($Paranoia);
echo '<br />';
var_dump($Paranoia2);
echo '<br />';
var_dump(unserialize(db_string($Paranoia)));
echo '<br />';
var_dump(unserialize($Paranoia2));
```

return:

```
string(41) "a:1:{i:0;s:13:"notifications";}" 
string(21) "a:1:{i:0;s:4:"test";}" 
bool(false) 
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the string returned from the query, just before you're unserializing it?

Comment: No problem, look the edit

Comment: Can you also vardump the result of `db_string($Paranoia)`? And then can you also inspect the source (`ctrl-u`) of the page that has the output to make sure there's no encoding issues?

Comment: Yeah, what does your `db_string` function perform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, as seen here:

```
string(41) "a:1:{i:0;s:13:"notifications";}"
```

or the string is 31 not 41...

[SOLUTION FOUND - Same strings, but var_dump() says one is 5 characters longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340621/solution-found-same-strings-but-var-dump-says-one-is-5-characters-longer)

so the solution:

```
html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: This happens when you don’t store the plain data in the database. Why did you encode the HTML special characters anyway?

Comment: `db_string` not a standard function/method. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: My bad!
It prepare the string for db insertion, so basically esaceping quotes! :)

Comment: There is no need to escape HTML special characters when inserting into the database, do it only when printing into HTML.