# Unserialize not working for multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

So I have run into this problem many times before, but I would always get around it using *base64_encode/decode* and that would get it working right away.

However, in this application **I cannot use that**, because I need to be able to query this field and I wouldn't know how I could do that if it was encoded.

Pardon my ignorance, but is there a way to unserialize a multi-dimensional array without using base64 encoding?

## Update 1

Removing the strings and turning them to integers fixes the problem. So it is either a problem with strings, or I suspect the " is causing issues. Anyway to work around that?

For this application, the second element of the array represents a date in a format that it would be searched under. Ideally, I would like to leave that as is, but if it is necessary I suppose I can use an integer to represent the number of days away from a constant, and then interpret that result.

### Below is the code:

```
// Load Contact from Database
$returnFields = array('_AttendanceRecords');
$Contact = $app->loadCon(39732,$returnFields);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($Contact);
echo "</pre>";

echo $Contact['_AttendanceRecords'] . "</br>";

// To unserialize...
$AttendanceRecordsLoad = unserialize($Contact['_AttendanceRecords']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($AttendanceRecordsLoad);
echo "</pre>";
```

### Output is:

> Array (
>       [_AttendanceRecords] => a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:10:"10-09-2015";i:2;s:1:"1";}} )
>
> a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:10:"10-09-2015";i:2;s:1:"1";}}

As you can see, the final print_r comes out empty, which I believe is returning false for whatever reason.

## Update 2

So after more fiddling around, I made this new code:

### Code

```
$ContactId = 39732;
$returnFields = array('_AttendanceRecords');
$Contact = $app->loadCon($ContactId,$returnFields);

echo $Contact['_AttendanceRecords'] . " - IS result </br>";
echo $str = 'a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:8:"10-10-15";i:2;i:1;}}'; echo " - str result </br>";
// To unserialize...

$AttendanceRecordsLoad = unserialize($Contact['_AttendanceRecords']);
$AttendanceRecordsLoad1 = unserialize($str);

echo "IS<pre>";
print_r($AttendanceRecordsLoad);
echo "</pre>";

echo "str<pre>";
print_r($AttendanceRecordsLoad1);
echo "</pre>";
```

### Output

> a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:8:"10-10-15";i:2;i:1;}} - IS result
>
> a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:8:"10-10-15";i:2;i:1;}} - str result
>
> IS
>
> str
>
> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 0
>               [1] => 10-10-15
>               [2] => 1
>           )
>
> )

I don't understand. The strings appear identical. Yet the result that comes from the database won't unserialize if it contains a string.

*Does that make sense to anyone?*

## Update 3

Ok, so now I used var_dump instead of echo and I get this outputted:

### Output

> string(61) "a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:8:"10-10-15";i:2;i:1;}}" - IS
>   result
>
> string(51) "a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;i:0;i:1;s:8:"10-10-15";i:2;i:1;}}" - str result

So obviously they are not identical. But I tried trim before, and now, and it doesn't remove any hidden extra characters that somehow have lodged themselves in to this string.

What does that mean and how do I correct this?

Comment: Tried to reproduce, the data seems to unserialize just fine. It's also not very clear what you are trying to do as I don't see the relevance of base64 in this situation.

Comment: @spenibus - Thanks for taking the time to try this. 

I'm not sure what the problem is.

I only mentioned base64 because if I use base64_encode, I can pass strings into a serialized array and unserialize them no problem. Reference link: http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out by looking at this question: 
[SOLUTION FOUND - Same strings, but var_dump() says one is 5 characters longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340621/solution-found-same-strings-but-var-dump-says-one-is-5-characters-longer)

The fix was using this on the returned result from the database:

```
html_entity_decode($string], ENT_QUOTES)
```

Hope that helps someone else too.